# Single php query to select and update

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a messaging app that allows users to delete their messages, below is a query that is to do just that, I want to select a message based on its ID then if its the recipient deleting the messaging who in this case is the (to_id), the column user1delete will be updated with a '1', if it is the sender the column user2delete will be updated with a 1, below are three queries I want to integrate into one or better how can I select a message based on its ID and update the selected row?

```
            $query = "Select subject ,id, to_id, from_id, user_from, message, time_sent FROM pm
   WHERE id = $id"; 

$result = $db->query($query);

    $query = "UPDATE pm SET user1delete = '1'
    WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN to_id = $to_id
    THEN from_id != $to_id
    END";

     $result = $db->query($query);

    $query = "UPDATE pm SET user2delete = '1'
    WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN from_id = $to_id
    THEN to_id != $to_id
    END";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any question rewriting will be greatly appreciated. Insert some newlines and split it into paragraphs to make it readable. Database query questions also are best accompanied by some table structures/graphs.

Comment: I want to update the row that the first query will select, how can I implement that based on the provided queries?

Comment: How can I select using the first query and update using the second query?

Comment: assuming your row has a `primary key`, which it looks like it does (the `id` field). simply use that in the `where` clause of the `update`

Comment: so basically there is no way I can use this query " $query = "Select subject ,id, to_id, from_id, user_from, message, time_sent FROM pm
   WHERE id = $id" to select a row then use this query "$query = "UPDATE pm SET user1delete = '1'
    WHERE 
    CASE
    WHEN to_id = $to_id
    THEN from_id != $to_id
    END" to work on the selected row?

Comment: of course there is. i just told you how. you use the `id` from the first query as the `where` clause in the second

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never got the concept there but now I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Pala, instead of selecting using the first query all I had to do include the id to the where clause below is my solution:

```
$query = "UPDATE pm SET user1delete = '1'
WHERE 
CASE
WHEN to_id = $to_id
THEN from_id != $to_id
AND id = $id
END";
$result = $db->query($query);


//$result = $db->query($query);

$query = "UPDATE pm SET user2delete = '1'
WHERE 
CASE
WHEN from_id = $to_id
  THEN to_id != $to_id
  AND id = $id
  END";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: How is this a single query?

Comment: its not, that was the closet I came up with, at least its 2 now instead of 3

Comment: but if you have a suggestion please share, I will be very happy